# VBA Strange RegEx Issue

Tags: regex, excel, vba, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am using Visual Basic in Excel to change some data

The pattern:

```
"^(" & Chr(167) & "\s)(\d+\:\d+)\.(\w+.*$)"
```

In some cases, the text is:

```
§ 34:149.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

and I want to separate the text into

`34:149` in the current cell and then `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"` in the next column

The problem I'm having is when the given values look like this:

```
§ 53:178.40
```

The RegEx returns this:
`53:178` as one group and then `.40` as the other

I can't get consistency on the returned subexpressions group because with `nnn:nnn.nn, .nn` is returned as an additional group as opposed to a member of the the already delineated group.

I'm confused with the operation here. I'm missing something, 
because I would expect any entries of the form `NN:NN.NN` to be rejected as matches.

After 40 minutes of trial and error, I can't figure the glitch.

The RegEx code snippet is:

```
strPattern = "^(" & Chr(167) & "\s)(\d+\:\d+)\.(\w+.*$)"
replaceString = "$2"
replaceString = "$2$3"
replaceString2 = "$4"

RE.Global = True
RE.MultiLine = True
RE.IgnoreCase = False
RE.pattern = strPattern

result1 = RE.Replace(source, replaceString)
result2 = RE.Replace(source, replaceString2)
```

Comment: `\w` matches digits, too. Use `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: On a side note, `Chr(167)` is locale-dependent. You probably want to use [`ChrW$(167)`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a7/index.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` matches digits, too. Use `[a-zA-Z]` instead to match any ASCII letter (you do not even need `+` after it):

```
"^(" & Chr(167) & "\s)(\d+:\d+)\.([a-zA-Z].*$)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HC7REt/1)

Also, `:` is not a special regex metacharacter, it needs no escaping.

In case you want to make sure the char after `.` is not a digit use `[^0-9]` or `\D` after `\.`:

```
^(§\s)(\d+:\d+)\.(\D.*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HC7REt/3). If it cannot be a whitespace either use

```
^(§\s)(\d+:\d+)\.([^\d\s].*)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/HC7REt/4).

Comment: Thanks that got me the results I needed. Agh!. I forgot the case when the text is leading with -, --, and ---

Comment: @KenIngram Which text?

Comment: E.g. § 34:149.-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet OR § 34:149.--Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Comment: @KenIngram Then just check if that char is not a digit: `^(§\s)(\d+:\d+)\.([^0-9].*)` or `^(§\s)(\d+:\d+)\.(\D.*)`.

Comment: These tips have helped get the results I was seeking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pattern like `^(§\s)([0-9:.]*)\.(\w+.*$)` see https://regex101.com/r/VGg7TJ/2

So this would just accept any matching numbers until the text starts.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tip. I will look at this closer once I get some sleep. RegEx plotting can be exhausting....

Comment: `^(§\s)(\d+:\d+(?>\.\d+)*)\.(\w+.*$)` won't work in VBA regex since the library only supports ECMAScript 5 that does not support atomic groups nor possessive quantifiers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew eww, you were right, missed that one. Changed my answer.

Comment: I see, but look at what OP says: *I would expect any entries of the form NN:NN.NN to be rejected as matches.* Your regex [matches them](https://regex101.com/r/VGg7TJ/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Doh, you are totally right, my bad. Need more coffee. You got my points.

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to regex101.com. I think it will be a critical resource. That alone was a worthwhile comment.

Comment: @KenIngramBe careful with regex101: it does not support VBA regex syntax now,  after JavaScript started supporting ES6 and especially ECMAScript 2018 standards. What works online does not have to work in VBA code.